# Clear list of components by clicking button

Tags: reactjs

I want to clear list of added divs by clicking CLEAR, button ADD is working its duplicating div, but I don't know how to figured it out how CLEAR button should work.

```
import React from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";
import ParentComponent from "./ParentComponent";

class A extends React.Component {
    state = {
      numChildren: 0
    }
  
    render () {
      const children = [];
  
      for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
        children.push(<ChildComponent key={i} number={i} />);
      };
  
      return (
        <ParentComponent addChild={this.onAddChild}>
          {children}
        </ParentComponent>
      );
    }
  
    onAddChild = () => {
      this.setState({
        numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1
      });
    }
  }

  export default A;
  

import React from "react";

const ChildComponent = props => <div>{"I am child " + props.number} </div>;

export default ChildComponent;


import React from "react";
import {Button} from '@material-ui/core';
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";



const ParentComponent = props => (
    <div className="card calculator">
         <Button href="#" onClick={props.addChild} >
            <AddIcon />
            ADD
          </Button> 
          <Button href="#" >
          CLEAR
          </Button>
      <div id="children-pane">
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  export default ParentComponent;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO8EL.png)

I want to clear list of added divs by clicking CLEAR, button ADD is working its duplicating div, but I don't know how to figured it out how CLEAR button should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your clear button should simply set **numChildren** to 0.

Add this to your **A** class:

```
clearChildren = () => {
  this.setState({
    numChildren: 0
  })
}
```

pass this method to **ParentComponent**

```
<ParentComponent addChild={this.onAddChild} clearChildren={this.clearChildren}>
          {children}
        </ParentComponent>
```

assign this to CLEAR button

```
<Button href="#" onClick={props.clearChildren}>
          CLEAR
          </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

in A component update props

```
<ParentComponent addChild={this.onAddChild} removeChilds={this.onRemoveChilds} {children}</ParentComponent>
```

and add remove function

```
onRemoveChilds = () => {
  this.setState({
     numChildren: 0
  });
};
```

Then in ParentComponent

```
<button href="#" onClick={props.removeChilds}>
  CLEAR
</button>
```